# Variance of estimated proportions

Tags: variance, proportion

Suppose I have a series of groups - each group a series of 0 or 1 so we can calculate a proportion for each group. Each group has different true proportions. Can anyone provide a formula for how the variance of the estimated proportions partition into the variance of the true proportions and the imprecision of the estimate of each individual proportion (p(1-p)/n).

Comment: How many proportions do you have?  That makes a difference.

Comment: o dear - many thanks, Michael. I maybe should have said that the oveall study was to inform a sample size calculation. We were hoping this could be regarded as pilot data to obtain average proportion and variance between proportions - then in a second study we hoped to be able to work out an optimal combination of number of groups and number of 0s and 1s per group (total binomial number ni or "run length) obviously the ni will determine precision of each group proportion. I guess we'd expect 10 or at most a few dozen groups

Comment: Then how many groups are there?

Comment: sorry for delay, Michael, shall we say 20 groups ? but each with a lot of 0s and 1 (100s) to for the proportion

Comment: is there a diffferent approach or formula depending whether you have a  lot of groups each with their own true and estiate proportion - or fewer groups. It'd be really useful please to know what the two approaches are and roughly where the cutoff between small and lrge numbers of groups may be (or does it depend on the size of the individual groups ?) - any brief hints are much appreciated thank you

Comment: I'm now wondering if I had such a series of binary data each with different true proportion I can use glmer (glmms) and the variability of the true proportions would be the estimated variance of the random effects - each group specifying a randmo effect. I wonder if that is why Prof Chernick aske how many groups as that seems more valid with a fair few groups I have this code to try and do this but it doesn't seem to work - I get an SD of around 0.43 even with 100 groups whch is different to the sd=0.1 I specify when I generate the "true" proportions with an SD of 0.1

Comment: ```{}library(lme4)

ng<-100

props<-runif(ng,0,1)

ni<-rpois(ng,100)

props<-rnorm(ng,0.6,0.1)
  
pi<-rbinom(ng,ni,props)


gpno<-as.factor(1:ng)

M5 <- glmer(cbind(pi,ni-pi) ~ 1 + (1|gpno), family=binomial)
M5 ```